# Rails: Nested dropdown of categories

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

I am using the ancestry gem to allow Categories to nest, and I want to be able to create a dropdown showing the nesting when a user selects a category for a new product.

I can create the nested list, but it uses the parent categories as labels for option groups instead of as selectable elements.

#### First attempt

```
<%= select_tag "product[category_id]",
        option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@store.categories, :children, :name, :id, :name, @product.category.id),
        { include_blank: true } %>
```

Which generates something like this:

```
<select id="product_category_id" name="product[category_id]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <optgroup label="Root Category 1"></optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Root Category 2">
    <option value="3">Child Category 1</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

When what I really want is just:

```
<select id="product_category_id" name="product[category_id]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Root Category 1</option>
  <option value="2">Root Category 2</option>
  <optgroup>
    <option value="3">Child Category 1</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

#### Other attempts

I also tried generating the list with content tags:

```
def grouped_options(categories, selected_id = nil)
  body = ''
  categories.map do |category|
    body << content_tag(:option, category.name, { value: category.id, selected: category.id == selected_id })
    if category.children.present?
      body << content_tag(:optgroup) do
        grouped_options(category.children)
      end
    end
  end
  body.html_safe
end
```

However, this approach left gaps in the list where the optgroup label should be, and you can't really go more than 1 level deep.

#### So...

Is there a way I can nicely nest everything in a select and be able to select each level, or should I start considering a javascript/unordered list implementation instead?